# Celery: How to turn off task acknowledgment?

Tags: performance, rabbitmq, celery

How to turn off ack-ing tasks in celery totally? The only option related to acknowledgment is [CELERY_ACKS_LATE](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#std%3asetting-CELERY_ACKS_LATE), but it only controls the time for sending acks, not turning them off.

The [RabbitMQ Performance Measurements](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/04/25/rabbitmq-performance-measurements-part-2/) article, compared rabbitmq performance with various flags/options, and it shows that turning on acknowledgment adds ~50% overhead. 
(I knew the performance of ~30k/s is still very high for most of cases, but the question remains)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for [ignore_result](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#ignore-results-you-don-t-want)? As far as I can tell, a task cannot be removed from the queue until it has been acknowledged. See also the [glossary entry on acknowledged](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/glossary.html#term-acknowledged).

Comment: No, It's completely unrelated to results (and result backends)